# Add event to calendar using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web

I am looking for someone who can help me to add event to web calendar. I have created calendar using PHP and HTML (you can take a look at two scripts at the bottom). I also have table in DB where those events should be entered. That table has 4 columns ID, start date, end date and type. start date and end date should be entered using calendar on the web and type can be entered as text. Thank you for your time!

```
<?php

class Calendar { 

    public function __construct(){     
        $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }


    private $dayLabels = array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun");
    private $currentYear=0;
    private $currentMonth=0;
    private $currentDay=0;
    private $currentDate=null;
    private $daysInMonth=0;
    private $naviHref= null;  

    public function show() {

        $year  = null;
        $month = null;

        if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

            $year = $_GET['year'];

        }else if(null==$year){

            $year = date("Y",time());  

        }          

        if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

            $month = $_GET['month'];

        }else if(null==$month){

            $month = date("m",time());

        }                  

        $this->currentYear=$year;
        $this->currentMonth=$month;
        $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  
        $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                    '<div class="box">'.
                    $this->_createNavi().
                    '</div>'.
                    '<div class="box-content">'.
                        '<ul class="label">'.$this->_createLabels().'</ul>';   
                         $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                         $content.='<ul class="dates">';    
                         $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);

                         for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                             for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                 $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                             }
                         }

                         $content.='</ul>';
                         $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';
                         $content.='</div>';
                         $content.='</div>';
                         return $content;   
}


private function _showDay($cellNumber){

    if($this->currentDay==0){

        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

        if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

            $this->currentDay=1;

        }
    }

    if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

        $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

        $this->currentDay++;   

    }else{

        $this->currentDate =null;

        $cellContent=null;
    }


    return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</li>';
}


private function _createNavi(){

    $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

    $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this->currentYear;

    $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

    $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this->currentYear;

    return
        '<div class="header">'.
            '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Prev</a>'.
                '<span class="title">'.date('Y M',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
            '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Next</a>'.
        '</div>';
}


private function _createLabels(){  

    $content='';

    foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

        $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' title">'.$label.'</li>';

    }

    return $content;
}




private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if( null==($year) ) {
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 
    }

    if(null==($month)) {
        $month = date("m",time());
    }


    $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

    $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

    $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

    $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

    if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

        $numOfweeks++;

    }

    return $numOfweeks;
}


private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if(null==($year))
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 

    if(null==($month))
        $month = date("m",time());

    return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
}
```

}

second script

```
<html>
<head>   
<title>Booker</title>
<link href="calendar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'calendar.php';

$calendar = new Calendar();

echo $calendar->show();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want help inserting data into a table?

Comment: This seems a little broad

Answer (score 1):

you can simply user this function

```
<?php
class ICS {
    var $data;
    var $name;
    function ICS($start,$end,$name,$description,$location) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($start))."\nDTEND:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($end))."\nLOCATION:".$location."\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\nSEQUENCE:0\nUID:\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\nSUMMARY:".$name."\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\nPRIORITY:1\nCLASS:PUBLIC\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGER:-PT10080M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:Reminder\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR\n";
    }
    function save() {
        file_put_contents($this->name.".ics",$this->data);
    }
    function show() {
        header("Content-type:text/calendar");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->name.'.ics"');
        Header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->data));
        Header('Connection: close');
        echo $this->data;
    }
}
?>
```